# JSON parsing for an array with two arraylists inside

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to parse the following API data. I just have to use the start time, end time, location and event name inside my app. I have never parse this type of data before. Hitting the API URL and getting a response is working fine, I just need help in parsing.

I have tried these solutions but it didn't work.

- parsing JSON 2 arrays (embedded) in Android
- How to Parsing JSON (Two Dimensional) array Object in android?
- How to parse `JsonArray` and JSON Object having two keys and values in android?
- Ask Android parsing JSON multiple arrays.

JSON:

```
     [
    {
    "end": {
    "endDate": "2018-03-09",
    "endTime": "03:00",
    "_id": "5a901a7d9fee7d156d594b04"
    },
    "location": "Dance Tent",
    "start": {
    "startDate": "2018-03-09",
    "startTime": "02:00",
    "_id": "5a901a7d9fee7d156d594b05"
    },
    "announcementName": "Jumanji Dance Party"
    }
]
```

Code:

```
    final JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(DATA_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    for (int index = 0; index < response.length(); index++) {


                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(index);
                                String fullName = jsonObject.getString("startTime");
                                String about = jsonObject.getString("announcementName");
                                String artistType = jsonObject.getString("endTime");
                                String link = jsonObject.getString("location");
                                //String avatar = jsonObject.getString("avatar");

                               Annoucement_Day_One artistInfoGetter=new Annoucement_Day_One( fullName,about, artistType, link );
                                annoucementDayOneList.add(artistInfoGetter);
                                wednesdayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();                                    
                            }

                        }}

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("ERRROR RES: ", error.toString());
                    myInstance.dismiss();

                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(response);

        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

            JSONObject object=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String location=object.getString("location");
            String announcementName=object.getString("announcementName");

            JSONObject end=object.getJSONObject("end");

            String endDate=end.getString("endDate");
            String endTime=end.getString("endTime");
            String id=end.getString("_id");


            JSONObject start=object.getJSONObject("start");

            String startDate=start.getString("startDate");
            String startTime=start.getString("startTime");
            String start_id=start.getString("_id");


        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,

```
for (int index = 0; index < response.length(); index++) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(index);

            JSONObject startJson = jsonObject.getJSONObject("start");
            String startTime = startJson.getString("startTime");

            JSONObject endJson = jsonObject.getJSONObject("end");
            String endTime = endJson.getString("endTime");

            String announcementName = jsonObject.getString("announcementName");
            String location = jsonObject.getString("location");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is giving me start time and end time but not annoucementName and location

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<Holder1> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
            for(int index = 0 ;index < jsonArray.length() ; index++){
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);
                //make a holder for end, location, start,announcementName
                Holder1 holder = new Holder1();
                holder.setLocation(jsonObject1.optString("location"));
                holder.setAnnouncementName(jsonObject1.optString("announcementName"));
                //------------
                JSONObject jsonObjectEnd =jsonObject1.getJSONObject("end");
                holder.setEndDate(jsonObjectEnd.optString("endDate"));
                holder.setEndTime(jsonObjectEnd.optString("endTime"));
                holder.setEndID(jsonObjectEnd.optString("_id"));
                //--------------
                JSONObject jsonObjectStart =jsonObject1.getJSONObject("start");
                holder.setStartDate(jsonObjectStart.optString("startDate"));
                holder.setStartTime(jsonObjectStart.optString("startTime"));
                holder.setStartID(jsonObjectStart.optString("_id"));
                //--------------
                arrayList.add(holder);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Accept the answer. If you like the way i have written.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `GSON` library by google.

add the dependency in build.gradle.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

First, you have to create the model class for your JSON response. [this](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/) will help you to create the model class.

```
 public class MyPojo
{
    private Start start;

    private String location;

    private String announcementName;

    private End end;

    public Start getStart ()
    {
        return start;
    }


    public String getLocation ()
    {
        return location;
    }


    public String getAnnouncementName ()
    {
        return announcementName;
    }


    public End getEnd ()
    {
        return end;
    }



}
```

--------------Start.Java------------

```
 public class Start
    {
        private String startTime;

        private String startDate;

        private String _id;

        public String getStartTime ()
        {
            return startTime;
        }

        public String getStartDate ()
        {
            return startDate;
        }


        public String get_id ()
        {
            return _id;
        }

        }
```

------------End.Java-------------------

```
public class End
{
    private String _id;

    private String endDate;

    private String endTime;

    public String get_id ()
    {
        return _id;
    }

    public String getEndDate ()
    {
        return endDate;
    }

    public String getEndTime ()
    {
        return endTime;
    }
}
```

Now in your onResponse method

```
       MyPojo respnse = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), MyPojo.class);
```

you can access any method from response.Ex. `response.getEnd().getEnd_date()`